# What is the integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I used trig substitution and got 
$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{7\tan \theta}{343\sec ^3\theta}d\theta$

Then simplified to sin and cos functions, using U substitution with a final answer of:
$\dfrac{-7}{3x^3}+C$

Which section did I go wrong in. Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Alternately, let $x=7\cosh t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let $x=7 \sec \theta$ then you won't get $7 \tan \theta$ in the numerator since $\sec^2\theta -\tan^2\theta =1$.

When the sub is done correctly you'll get an integral of the form  $\displaystyle \frac{49}{343} \int \frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}\,d\theta = \frac{1}{7} \int \sin^2\theta\ d\theta = \frac{1}{14}\int (1-\cos 2\theta)\ d\theta$ and the rest should be easy.

Comment: I mistyped a sign. That should be better.

Comment: But where is the $dx = 7\sec\theta\,\tan\theta\, d\theta$ term?

Comment: that would be where i went wrong. Thank you

Comment: np. It is much simpler with this term in.

Comment: Ill give it another go and tell you what I get.

Comment: $\frac{\textrm{arcsec}\frac{x}{7}}{14} - \frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}{14x} + C$  is what I get

Comment: Tyler, you need an extra $x$ in the denominator of the second term and the $14$ should be replaced by $2$. See MathNoob's answer below.

Comment: Thanks I made another small algebra error. I should go to bed!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}{x^3}$$
$$=\int \frac{7\sec \theta\tan\theta\sqrt{49\sec^2 \theta-49}}{\sec^3 \theta}$$
$$=\int \frac{49\tan^2 \theta}{7^3\sec^2 \theta}$$
$$=\frac{1}{7}\int {\sin^2 \theta}$$

Can you find $\int \sin^2 \theta$?

Hint: $\sin^2 x= \dfrac 12 (1-\cos 2\theta)$

Comment: I can, but I'm not sure where the $sec^2\theta$ term came from in your second step.

Comment: $x=\tan\theta$ doesn't get rid of the square root as $\tan^2\theta -1 \neq \sec^2\theta$....

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you need to substitute x= $7sec\theta$ instead

Comment: @Tyler Right you are.

Comment: Yes I can I'm just about done I'll keep you posted

Comment: One other possible correction, I am getting 1/7 as a constant instead of 7

Comment: My final answer is now$\frac{\textrm{arcsec}\frac{x}{7}}{14} - \frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}{14x} + C$

Comment: something not right with second term I think ...

Comment: @MathNoob then it's a typo in your answer as there is now an extra $x$ in the denominator after you take the square root in the second term.

Comment: I got $$\frac{1}{14}(\theta-\sin \theta \cos \theta)\implies \frac{1}{14}(\sec^{-1} (x/7) \sin \sec^{-1} (x/7)-\cos\sec^{-1} (x/7))\implies \frac{\sec^{-1} (x/7)}{14}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-{49}}}{2x^2}$$

Comment: @MathNoob Ah, it was Tyler that needed the extra $x$ in his denominator not yours. Sorry. Yes I saw your extra $x$ in the square root but it looks better if you take a denominator etc.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, letting $x=7\cosh t$, and using the fact that $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1,~\cosh't=\sinh t$, and $\sinh't=\cosh t$, we ultimately arrive at $$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sinh^2t}{\cosh^3t}dt=\int\frac{\sinh^2t~\cosh t}{\cosh^4t}dt=\int\frac{\sinh^2t\cdot d\big(\sinh t\big)}{\big(1+\sinh^2t\big)^2}=\int\frac{u^2}{\big(1+u^2\big)^2}du,~$$ which is trivial.